# Software center crashes; fieldrunners need to be reinstalled; can't find achive

Tags: software-center, dependencies, archive

> Could not initialize the package information. An unresolvable problem
>   occurred while initializing the package information. Please report
>   this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the
>   following error message: 'E:The package fieldrunners needs to be
>   reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'

This is preventing me from opening Software Center and installing/uninstalling just about everything. How do I remove this fieldrunners or replace said missing archive?

```
An error occurred, please run package manager from the right-click menu or the apt-get in terminal to see what is wrong.  
The error message was '<type' exception.systemError'>' 
(E:The package fieldrunners needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.)'. 
This usually means that your  installed packages have unmet dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following commands in a terminal and then see if your problem has been fixed or not -

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: rm: cannot remove `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*': No such file or directory was the result of the remove command

Comment: tried to $ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package fieldrunners needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
john@ubuntu:~$